# How to open jquery tool overly on form submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am having [overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/apple.html) while clicking on the link.I want to open the same Overlay while 
submitting form.How can i do this.

```
<a  id="add_to_cart" rel="#note">myOverlay</a> 

var triggers = $("#add_to_cart[rel]").overlay({
    oneInstance: false,
    closeOnClick: false,
    mask:'#000',
    onLoad: function() {
        setTimeout('$("#add_to_cart[rel]").data("overlay").close();', 1000);
    }
});
```

This is working fine

```
function FormSubmitAjax(event)
{

// I want to open the same overlay here         
 triggers.overlay();

 event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

How can i do this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#add_to_cart[rel]").data("overlay").load();
```